# Extract path from shape, and preferably merge it with another path from a shape

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, path

I have two different shapes, one that looks like a drop and one that is a square. The drop was made using the pen tool.

Now, I want to merge these two shapes, combine their paths to create the illusion of the drop transforming into a square.

**I can't figure out how to extract the path of the square, so that I can manipulate its anchor points.**

Googling it didn't help me much.

Comment: I'm not sure what it is you want to achieve. Maybe moving the two paths on top of each other, selecting them both and hitting the 'unite' button in the Pathfinder palette will help?

Comment: @Bakabaka I guess what I'm really after is how to draw a shape using the shape tool, like a square, and have its anchor points accessible and editable once its drawn.

Comment: That's what the white arrow tool is for, right?

Comment: @Bakabaka yea, I just figured it out by selecting the Pen tool, holding Ctrl and dragging across the shape (a bit of a trial and error approach) and that got me the selection I was after. The Path selection / Direct selection tools had totally escaped me... thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As  I found by trial and error and what Bakabaka also pointed out was that I wanted to use the Direct selection tool (white arrow). I "accidently" acquired it by selecting the Pen tool and holding Ctrl while dragging across the shape, which basically activates the Direct selection tool.